# How to achieve <ngx-customname></ngx-customname> in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am new to the Angular world, I tried to find the answer to my question in every possible way but unable to do so.

In below code, I am running div tag in a for loop where I need to insert an ngx-module(as I am not sure about the exact naming conventions), but module name should be based on some user input. Let's say I have all the module(different pages) names stored in a string array. I need to iterate through all selected array items and add those pre-defined module templates.

Any suggestions or answers are appreciable.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-select-ex I tried with this example, but I am not sure that I am in the right path.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor = "let selectedMenuItems of selectedMenuItems let i = index">
  <div class="col-xxxl-3 col-xxl-4 col-lg-5 col-md-6">
     <ngx-selectedMenuItems ></ngx-selectedMenuItems>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at how to dynamically load components here https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader.

It's really simple, all you need are these lines of code:

```
// The template where we will dynamically load components
<ng-template host></ng-template>

// Here you should run some check against the user input to decide which component to load
let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(foo.component);

// Get the ng-template
let viewContainerRef = this.host.viewContainerRef;
viewContainerRef.clear();

// Set some data in the component you loaded
let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
(<FooComponent>componentRef.instance).data = bar.data;
```

Make sure to change the `foo.component`/`<FooComponent> and`bar.data` parts in this example for your needs.

I recommend reading the entire article to gain a better understanding how this works.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The answer is matching to my requirement with slite modification. The example in the above link replaces the current template. But in my requirement, I need all the templates side by side. I dont need replacement of the templates. Let me know if you can help me.

Comment: @PrasadPH Remove your template with the `*ngFor` and loop in your component instead. Have a main `ng-template` which you load the surrounding divs etc using `Renderer2` and then you load your component into the `ng-template` within each loop iteration. Then move the `.clear()` call to the place where you loop to clear the template before looping. I understand if this is slightly confusing but it's hard to give a really detailed example on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in another way. Use ng-if to match the name of component with array item

```html
<div class="row" *ngFor="let itemName of selectedMenuItems">
  <div class="col-xxxl-3 col-xxl-4 col-lg-5 col-md-6">
     <ngx-Squirtle *ngIf="itemName=='Squirtle'"></ngx-Squirtle>
     <ngx-pikachu *ngIf="itemName=='pikachu'"></ngx-pikachu>
     <ngx-Bulbasaur *ngIf="itemName=='Bulbasaur'"></ngx-Bulbasaur>
  </div>
</div>
```